# MS SqlServer tcp proxy

Tags: windows, sql-server

Is there a way to proxy a SqlServer connection through port 80? Maybe by using Fiddler?

My machine is in network1 and the proxy machine and SqlServer are in network2 (there are no restrictions between machines in network2).

The only open ports between network1 and network2 are port 80 and 443.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Reverse SSH Tunnel.

[https://toic.org/blog/2009/reverse-ssh-port-forwarding/](https://toic.org/blog/2009/reverse-ssh-port-forwarding)

On network 1 run a [SSH Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers) on port 443, on the proxy machine on network 2 run a SSH client such as Putty to connect out of the network and open a way in. In the guide for your example it will be the last one connecting to the printer inside the network.

One other thing to keep in mind is that SQL Server by default when using named instances uses dynamic port allocation, if this is the case you will need to configure the SQL Server to use a fixed port if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks! will be trying this. I wonder if it is possible to proxy UDP packets as most SqlClients use UDP packets to discover available SqlServers? or am I totally incorrect here?

Comment: It discovers the instances not servers. that's what he mean dynamic port allocation. configure a fixed port, or set the correct dynamic TCP port and instance Name  directly in your client, some client can skip the discovery if you get those setting right.